# Passing form selected data to controller in laravel7, returns null

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-7

- I need to pass selectbox selected data to Laravel Controller.
- But It always return null.
- What is wrong in my code, Thanks You.

  ```
  <td class="mr-3">                                           
    <select class="form-control" name="section[]" id="section" value="">
  <option>Select Section</option>

  @foreach ($sections as $key => $value) {{ $value }}
   <option value="{{ $key }}" {{ ( $key == $selectedID) ? 
       'selected' : '' }}>

   {{ $value }}
    </option>
   @endforeach
   </select>
   </td>
  ```
- In my Controller:

  ```
   public function store(Request $request)
   {
    foreach($request->input('sections') as $key => $value){
    $data['value'] = $key;
  }
     dd ($data['value']);  // <- Returns Null !
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the name with out []

```
<select class="form-control" name="section" id="section" >
```

in the controller

```
  $data['value'] = $request->input('sections');
```

if you want multiple selection

```
      <select  multiple="multiple" name="sections[]" id="sections">
```

in the controller

```
       foreach($request->sections as $key ){
           $data['value'] []= $key;
              }
```